# How to switch git user at terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, git, github

I am trying to push a project to a remote repository from the command line.

From inside my local directory, I hit:

```
$ git push
```

and obtain the following error:

> remote: Permission to username1/repo.git denied to username2.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username1/repo.git/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 403

Where `username1` is my github account username hosting the repository I want to push to and `username2` is an old account I used to use on this machine.

I am using OS X Yosemite (v10.10.5) on a Macbook Air. And I would prefer to use *https* instead of *ssh*.

How do I update to `username1` so I can successfully push to my remote?

Edit: To be clear, I am not talking about simply editing the `config user` object, e.g.,

```
$ git config --global user.name "Billy Everyteen"
$ git config --global user.email "billyeveryteen@example.com"
```

They have nothing to do with authentication. My question deals with ***user authentication*** necessary to write to my remote repository.

Comment: [Setting your username in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

Comment: Thanks. But that only deals with setting the username. Not authentication. In other words, that documentation shows us how to associate the name of who gets credit for the commits. But it doesn't actually authorize the user to push commits.

Comment: You might be able to change it user the command documented at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials . Alternatively, if you want to clear the credentials, you might look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git .

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem!

Comment: what if I don't want to change local git settings?

Comment: just push once to another git using another user. I wounder WHY is it so hard to do.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In addition to changing username and email from terminal using `git config`:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Bob"
$ git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
```

you'll need to remove authorization info from Keychain. This is something I've also struggled with until I found that I also had certificate in my Keychain.

Open up Keychain access, click on All Items and search for `git`. You will get some items like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Delete them. Now try to push the repo and git will ask you to write password for the user and you will be good to go.

Comment: What about Windows users?

Comment: i have multiple accounts what should i do

Comment: I'm having the same issue with win7. I not sure what the solution is :(

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly

Comment: I used to do that but it's annoying when having to switch back and forth between accounts. This answer would be great for the question of how to make the system forget one's credentials; for changing account, I think the accepted answer should be https://superuser.com/a/1245296/430259.

Comment: In case you're having trouble deleting the password after a search: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344380/350595

Answer (score 48):

For cli users, just use this :
  `git config credential.username 'Billy Everytee'`

Comment: You need to disable 2FA temporarily.

Comment: This wasn't enough for me. I also needed to set a different user.email using git config for the specific repo:

`git config user.email "bob@example.com"`

Answer (score 33):

List your git config.

```
git config --list
```

Change username and email global

```
git config --global user.name "Nanhe Kumar"
git config --global user.email "info@nanhekumar.com"
```

Change username and email for current repo

```
git config  user.name "Nanhe Kumar"
git config  user.email "info@nanhekumar.com"
```

Change your repo url if you are using bit bucket.

```
nano .git/config
```

This file will be something like this.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        fileMode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://nanhe@bitbucket.org/nanhekumar/myproject.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master`

    [user]
            name = Nanhe Kumar
            email = info@nanhekumar.com
```

Comment: This is the most thorough answer considering global and local repo scope.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "My question deals with user authentication necessary to write to my remote repository."

Comment: This is working perfectly

Comment: @Jie thanks but this like film industry if you edit not solution indentation content your earn point so i have long time not answring

Answer (score 28):

For Windows User:
Follow Instructions:
Control Panel >> User Account >> Credential Manager >> Windows Credential >> Generic Credential

remove git credential.
next time when you'll push repo it'll ask you for credential.
[Answer reference for detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592537/9790416)

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for on Windows.

Comment: @JCF Welcome! I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 8):

Other plausible option, if you wanted to use the "new user" on only one project, you can do it by configuring it just for the project's directory in which you are working. e.g:

```
 git config --local user.name "Mike"
 git config --local user.email "mike@example.com"
```

note that I'm using --local instead of --global.

Comment: Doesn't simply **omitting --global** create the same effect as "[Git will write to a local level if no configuration option is passed](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config)"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "My question deals with user authentication necessary to write to my remote repository."

Answer (score 2):

Solving the actual authentication issue, one needs to specify the correct remote, if the standard git config suggestions don't work.

If so, you're probably using an SSH key and it's in your keychain. When using a repository with a new user, make sure your SSH key is configured in `~/.ssh/config` [(handy link to instructions if you need to add a new key)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), like so:

```
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myFirstAccountKey
   IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-second-account
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mySecondAccountKey
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I'm not sure if the IdentitiesOnly attribute is required for either of the two.

Then update the remote origin of the repository you're having auth issues to use the second account:

```
git remote add origin git@github-second-account:[YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME]/[YOUR_GITHUB_REPO].git
```

See for more detail: https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/80a89405ab9023894df7

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows you can simply use GitManager (GitAccountManager on npm): https://github.com/paul-hanneforth/GitManager. There you can do it all with only one command.

Comment: Although it's reasonably obvious from the link & your user name, to prevent being potentially flagged as spam it's always better to make your affiliation clear in your post.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem. What i did was to remove the ssh key i had in my other account.

To explain in a better way. I have 2 accounts in the same computer and both accounts I have ssh keys, so it was confliting in the moment i tried to push in the newest account I created. So i logged in the oldest account and deleted the ssh key, then I tried pushing in my newest account and it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240320)